# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object With Array of objects

Tags: php, html-table

I had got this notice, when I try to foreach all my objects in Array:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object With Array of objects

What can I do to get all row of my Array to put them into a table?

```
foreach ($this->CollectionArray[$IdVisitor] as  $row) {
echo'<tr>';
 echo'<td>'.$row->number.'</td>';       
 echo'<td>'.$this->CollectionArray[$IdVisitor]->date.'</td>';
```

I got error in `echo'<td>'.$row->number.'</td>';`

ÉDIT: When I use only collectionArray without foreach it works, but only the last row is showed . It’s why I use foreach to get all rows

Comment: `var_dump($row);` what do you get?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show what `$this->CollectionArray[$IdVisitor]` has in it? Also, why do you do `$this->CollectionArray[$IdVisitor]->date` when `$this->CollectionArray[$IdVisitor]` was an array itself?

Comment: @aynber i got the object into my collectionarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it like this:

```
foreach ($this->CollectionArray as  $row) {
 echo'<tr>';
 echo'<td>'.$row->number.'</td>';       
 echo'<td>'.$row->date.'</td>';  
}
```

It will iterate over $this->CollectionArray, so you don't have to specify the index.

Comment: I had to speciy the index beacause i want only get row from a particular visitor

Comment: Can you inform what was the notice?
And also, if possible, the result of var_dump($row)

Comment: Do you want to print all that is inside $this->CollectionArray[$idVisitor] then?

Comment: Still doesn't have the notice or the variable.

Comment: Can you try $row['number'] ? Instead of $row->number

Comment: Now with you'r help I got : "Warning: Illegal string offset"

Comment: Can you print the result of $this->CollectionArray[$IdVisitor] and paste it here? 
You can print it with error_log(print_r($this->CollectionArray[$IdVisitor], 1)); 
Or with echo($this->CollectionArray[$IdVisitor]);

Comment: with error_log:  I got PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class VisitorClass could not be converted to string in C:\\xampp